# Bootstrap. Панель с меню не адаптивится под малый экран

Tags: bootstrap

[image: Выезжают за полосу хедера вниз]

Логотип и кнопка, скрывающая выползающие пункты, выезжает за пределы серого хедера
Как сделать так, чтобы они были на одной прямой и именно на уровне серого хедера, подскажите, пожалуйста

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #fbfcfb;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

header {
background-color: #00008B;
margin: 0;
font-size: 18px;
}

.menu {
  border: none;
}
.nav-left li,
.navbar-right li {
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.navbar-right li a{
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.navbar-logo img {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}

.nav-left li:hover,
.navbar-right li:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #32CD32;
}

.navbar-nav .active-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.glyphicon-contact {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000000;
  right: 165px;
  top: 5px;
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1198px) {

  .navbar-right {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 175px;
    top: 55px;
  }

.glyphicon-contact {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-right li {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar-right li a {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default menu">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand и toggle сгруппированы для лучшего отображения на мобильных дисплеях -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-logo" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" width="35"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Соберите навигационные ссылки, формы, и другой контент для переключения -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-left">
        <li class="active-link"><a href="#">Professional skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Interesting in web</a></li>
      </ul>


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li><a href="#"><img src="img/mail.png" height="" width="27"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="img/github.png" height="" width="26"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="img/linkedin.png" height="" width="27"></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt glyphicon-contact"></span>

  </div><!-- /.container-->
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: нету такого волшебного фреймворка который адаптирует что угодно под что угодно ... требуется или кастомизация или знания css

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы.